# Is it possible to burn the balances of a contract from another contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, tokens, erc-20

Imagine the scenario in which contract A has in its possession 1000 tokens (of the contract itself). is it possible to create a second contract and burn the tokens of contract A?

```
contract ContractA is DetailedERC20 {

    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;

    uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = (500 * (10**6)) * (10 ** uint256(decimals));

    constructor(string _name, string _symbol) 
    public 
    DetailedERC20(_name, _symbol, decimals)
    {
        totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
        balances[this] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
        emit Transfer(address(0), this, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    }
}
```

Contract B (**PSEUDO**)

```
contract ContractB {

    ERC20 public token;

    constructor(ERC20 _token) public {
        token = _token;
    }

    function burn() internal {
        token.balances[address(token)] = 0;
        token.totalSupply_ = 0;
    }
}
```

Sorry if looks strange, but i'm a noob in Solidity

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly as described but you can make the effect.

Starting with `ContractB` has some tokens to burn, you can:

1. With some foresight, create a proper burn function in `ContractA` and then call it from `ContractB` to destroy tokens and reduce the total supply.
2. Improvise by transferring the tokens (with the regular transfer function) to an address that makes them unspendable. A lot of processes send to `address(0)` for this purpose because it is presumed no one has (or ever will have) and private key for `0x0`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The contract A is already in the blockchain (Ropsten), so I can not use option 1. Regarding 2, I have no idea how to transfer the tokens of the contract balance to another address. Would you help me?

Comment: If the ContractB "has some tokens", doesn't this imply that ContractB is also deployed? If so, you are limited to ContractB's inbuilt functions, which hopefully include a function to send tokens away.